# strtotime returns a 1970 date when date column is null

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date

I want to display `$p->due_date` in `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

If the date column in database is null the date displayed is : 01-01-1970

```
<?=strftime(config_item('date_format'), strtotime($p->due_date))?>
```

If the date is null in database it should not display anything , otherwise the date in dd-mm-yyyy format should be displayed.

Thanks in advance

Daniel

Comment: if you don't insert date then it will be `0000-00-00` in the table by default, so check this that if date is not equal to this after that use *strtotime*

Comment: I'm confused. Your question is tagged with `mysql` and `sql-server`, but it seems like your actual question is about PHP? (At least, that looks like PHP, not like any weird sort of proprietary SQL syntax . . .)

Answer (score 0):

Is the date field in your database is nullable and if yes then it will return null thats correct and since strtotime expects date then it will display the unix epoch date i.e 01-01-1970. Just use the if condition or ternary operator to solve this..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(null)); // $date = '1970-01-01 01:00:00'
```

So you may write condition:

```
<?=($p->due_date ? strftime(config_item('date_format'), strtotime($p->due_date : '')))?>
```

or short condition via `?:`